# Absolute imports with DTS-CLI

Tags: reactjs, rollup

unfortunately I have hit a rock bottom. I am trying to search on if there is a possible way to integrate `baseUrl` imports with DTS-CLI. Does someone know more on the matter, because after countless hours of researching I haven't found anything.